# How to create template with a set of sealed class

Tags: c#

I have several sealed class from a code I can't rewrite. (therefore I can't not make those class implement a same interface).

I have several function that make the same thing for this class:

```
void fN(int i, sealedClassN sc)
{
    list.Add(new delegateCreator(sc));
    button.Click += list.[i]._delegate;
}
```

(and of course delegateCreator( sealedClassN ) is implemented (but without using template because what it does is very different each time))

I would like to create that:

```
void f<sealedClass >(int i, sealedClass sc) with sealedClass : sealedClass1or or sealedClass2 or sealedClass3 ....
{
    list.Add(new delegateCreator(sc));
    button.Click += list.[i]._delegate;
}
```

Is there a way to do that.
Thank you for your help

Comment: Are you asking about extension methods perhaps? In any case using inheritance just to add an extra method can lead to more trouble than is worth

Comment: What are you *really* trying to do? What is `delegateCreator` and why do you use that list? You're already adding multiple event handlers to a hidden list with `+=`. You don't need to create a delegate when you can just pass a lambda. Lists have indexer properties so you could just write `list[i]`. It's quite likely that you are overcomplicating things

Comment: For example, if you pass a *Func<object,EventArguments>* instead of a class, you no longer care about the classes themselves and get rid of `delegateCreator()`. The type problem disappears immediatelly. You can have a `List<Func<..>` if you want to keep track of the event handlers you used, although that doesn't sound very useful. Perhaps you really need to track the *classes* that are used in the handlers?

Comment: It isn't enough that the classes *look* the same, they have to *be* the same/have something in common, so unfortunately generics won't help you here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not directly possible. I can suggest the following alternatives:

Option 1: Pass a `delegateCreator` instead:

```
// call as fN(i, new delegateCreator(sc))
//
void fN(int i, delegateCreator dc)
{
    list.Add(dc);
    button.Click += list.[i]._delegate;
}
```

Option 2: If you have a more complicated function which only conditionally creates a `delegateCreator`, you can pass a lambda expression as the parameter:

```
// call as fN(i, () => new delegateCreator(sc))
//
void fN(int i, Func<delegateCreator> dcfunc)
{
    if (someCondition)
    {
        list.Add(dcfunc.Invoke());
        button.Click += list.[i]._delegate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do that. The problem with your `T : T1 or T2 ...` idea is that you don't have a shared member set for your argument.
Consider this

```
public class Type1
{
    public void M()
    {
    }
}

public class Type2
{
    public void M()
    {
    }
}

public static class Extension
{
    public static void A<T>(T obj) where T : Type1 or Type2
    {
        obj.M();
    }
}
```

Both classes have a methode `M()` but for the compiler it isn't the same, because they don't have a shared type that declares this methode.